# Convergence of a specific expression

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I would like to prove the convergence of what follows

$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{N}\left[(1+\frac{\alpha}{2^{2N+2}})^{2^{2n+1}}-(1+\frac{\alpha}{2^{2N+2}})^{2^{2n}}\right] < \infty
$$

where $\alpha$ is a real parameter. If needed one can assume $0\le\alpha\le1$, but numerical computations seem tu suggest the series converges for arbitrary positive $\alpha$. It is unclear if and how usual tests can be applied, since terms of the series depend on the partial sum upper boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace $n$ by $N-n$, then [take the limit termwise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem). For any real (or even complex) $\alpha$, the result is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(e^{\alpha/2^{2n+1}}-e^{\alpha/2^{2n+2}}\right)\color{gray}{=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\left(e^{\alpha/2^n}-1\right)}\color{LightGray}{=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\alpha^n}{n!(2^n+1)}}.$$